# How much extra wire should I buy to run to my sub panel?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I found a really good price on the wire I need to run from the main panel to my planned sub panel, but I want to buy the right amount.  How much extra should I purchase?

Assuming the main panel is on the outside of the house, and the sub panel will be 15 feet straight across from it, what length of wire should I buy?  The room has a 9' ceiling, and the wire will be in EMT run through the ceiling.  I figured I'd add 10' for each wall (even though the new sub panel won't be on the floor.  If I buy 35' (each of black, red, and white) is that too much?  Too little?  I don't want the electrician to be cursing me for buying too short of wire, but I also don't want to blow $40 on wire I don't need.

Comment: I would use a string.  Add up to a foot for the bends.  Inside of the panels might be a foot or more, depends where the wire comes in and where it needs to go.  If neutral has to go around the bottom or top to get to the other side, it will be extra for that wire.

Comment: For pricing, make sure you're buying aluminum, just want to make sure you got the good word. There's nothing wrong with aluminum at large heavy feeder sizes, and the terminals are aluminum rated (actually: made of aluminum).   If it's #4 or larger you don't need 3 colors.  Also make sure the electrician is OK with you buying the wire, most won't work with your stuff because they can't give a warranty on it.

Comment: How much extra you need depends on how precisely you know the path it will take. Ideally, you buy when the conduit is sitting there empty and you can actually measure the actual route the wires will take. *(Harper's Rule of "Buy the wire last!")* The further you are from that condition, the more you have to inflate your estimate to allow for the unknown unknowns.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Thanks for the advice, but it's 4/0 copper.  I don't want to use aluminum due to only being able to use 2" EMT.  It's a 200A sub panel, and I want to derate the wire a bit.

Comment: @crip659 Good idea.  I already have the conduit, and I'm pretty sure of the exact length of cable I "need" for the run.  I'm mainly looking for how much extra.  If you're saying a foot, then that's great.  I can do the string trick to get right to where the lugs are, then add a foot on each end if you think that's enough spare to work with.

Comment: I am not quite sure how much the bends will take.  It will be at least about a few inches extra for each bend.

Comment: I would say 6"+ for each bend. Interesting derate idea. I discourage copper when the money spent is then *not* spent on safety stuff that actually matters, like AFCIs, GFCIs, proper generator interlock instead of extension cords to appliances through cracked-open doors that let in CO, etc. Just had a guy propose copper "for safety" but only 3-wire (to keep costs down), /facepalm.   But yeah, once I had to use 1000 kcmil copper due to conduit constraints... ouch...  I wound up buying 10% extra for that job.

Comment: @crip659 I have a whole spool of cat8 cable I'm going to be running through the house.  I can use it to mock up the sub panel for length.  I'm toying with the idea of doing it myself since it's just going to connect to the pass-through lugs on an empty 200A outdoor panel.  I'm having 400A service installed with side-by-side 200A panels outside.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Oh believe me, I agree.  ALL of my breakers are AFCI or AFCI/GFCI where specified.  I got a stellar deal on BR series breakers just before everything fell apart in the supply chain.  I got the panels below regular retail, but I've just been delayed with other nonsense for the last few years due to the pandemic.  This project included a new driveway and lots of other stuff.  I put off the electrical until now.